# Grabbing JSON from a PHP file within separate JavaScript file

Tags: php, javascript, json, external

Needing to create a JavaScript file that sets values to two variables in a PHP file. That PHP file then creates a JSON structure and echoes some data.

I need a form in JavaScript where there is a form with the two inputs to assign to the PHP variables and then pull the JSON structure, and store the result in a HTML table.

Currently trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button1").click(function(event){
$.get("external.php", {variable_1: 'VALUE1', variable_2: 'VALUE2'),           function(JSONresult){
        alert (variable_1);
}, 'json');
});
});
```

Relevant PHP is:

```
$variable_1 = $_GET['variable_1'];
$variable_2 = $_GET['variable_2'];
// Some code in between that accesses a DB
echo json_encode($res->fetchAll());
```

Comment: So do it. We're not here to write code for you. If you run into problems when writing it, we can help you with that.

Comment: I have attempted this with a few different methods and been to no avail. So I'm asking for guidance as to how to achieve this. No need to be harsh :/.

Comment: My friend just post you code in you question, and we will see your effort, realize that almost all people here have jobs and things to do and answer a question for an unknown person is spend our time just because we want to help, every programmer needs help this is why stackoverflow exist!!. BUT we don't support persons who come just to request code without show any kind of effort.

Comment: I've updated the first post to show what I'm attempting.

Comment: where is the php code showing the variables being set from GET values and the echo json_encode? Also after VALUE2 you need a end curly brace, not an end parenthesis

Comment: Updated with info for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try

`console.log(JSONresult); console.log(JSONresult['variable_1']);`

You'll know where the values are.